# How to sort 'HOHOHOO!!!' in Haskell using any non-comparative integer sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, haskell

I am trying to sort 'HOHOHOO!!!' in Haskell using any non-comparative integer sorting algorithm, so that at the end I get '!!!HHHOOOO'..

I am only string with Haskell and have been sitting on it all day... Please, help!

All i got so far is this, but it doesn't allow to sort Letters. I think i need to use a Radix sort, but i Have no idea how.

```
merge [] l = l
merge l [] = l
merge l1@(x1:r1) l2@(x2:r2) =
if x1 < x2 then x1:(merge r1 l2) else x2:(merge l1 r2)

ssort [] = []
ssort l = merge strand (ssort rest)
where (strand, rest) = foldr extend ([],[]) l
      extend x ([],r) = ([x],r)
      extend x (s:ss,r) = if x <= s then (x:s:ss,r) else (s:ss,x:r)
```

Thank you,
Dasha

Comment: This definitely looks comparison-based to me. Are you supposed to be using some sort of radix sort?

Comment: `import Data.List (sort)` and `sort "HOHOHOO!!!"`.

Comment: @AaditMShah: `sort` is comparison based.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort should give you the info you need. Your life will be much easier if you use functions from `Data.Bits` instead of trying to stick with the `Prelude` ones. You should probably `import Data.Char (ord, chr)` also, to avoid needing to spray `toEnum` and `fromEnum` all over your code.

Comment: @dfeuer I have to use a non-comparative sorting. I was my guess that it should be a radix sort

Answer (score 4):

A counting sort is non-comparative and quite easy (a one-liner!) in Haskell:

```
import Data.Array

countingSort :: (Bounded a, Ix a, Num i) => [a] -> Array a i
countingSort = accumArray (+) 0 (minBound, maxBound) . flip zip (repeat 1)
```

Radix sort can be implemented with a similar technique, using data structures that reify radix lookups. See [IntMap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.2/docs/Data-IntMap.html) for sorting `Int`s, or browse the many memoization packages for interfaces that can handle other types of data.

Comment: I am sorry to addmit it, but your answer is too complicated for me... I tried putting in your code, but it doesn't work for me. Could you please explain it or do more a easier version of it?

Comment: @DashaVKravets "It doesn't work" isn't specific enough for me to give much more help, really. What did you do, exactly? What happened? (What error did you get?) What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @ Daniel Wagner I put import Data.Array
countingSort = accumArray (+) 0 (minBound, maxBound) . flip zip (repeat 1) in Notepad++, tried to reload in WinHugs and got "ERROR file:.\new  0.hs:69 - Unresolved top-level overloading
*** Binding             : countingSort
*** Outstanding context : (Bounded b, Ix b)"

Comment: @DashaVKravets Sounds like the monomorphism restriction. Try adding a type signature (I'll edit the answer shortly to show how).

Comment: @DashaVKravets, this isn't really relevant, but Hugs has not been maintained since 2006, so you should probably switch to GHC and GHCi for your Haskell adventures.

Comment: @DanielWagner, isn't this going to allocate a rather large array (on the order of a million entries), and then fill some unknown but small portion of it with counts that will not be so easy to use?

Comment: @dfeuer What's a few megabytes between friends? But yes, a sparse data structure -- e.g. `IntMap`, which I suggested in the answer -- may be more desirable in some cases.